# Spring Batch CommandLineJobRunner on linux

Tags: spring-batch

I am trying to run my job using SpringBatch-CommandLineJobRunner on Linux, I have the below jars in classpath. 
    Can anyone please take a look and see If I am missing any jars and tell me the missing jars. In our project they dont want to use any tools like Maven or STS, we are just using eclipse, our jobs run well from eclipse. On Linux we get the below errors.. we are using below command

java -cp org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner springbatch/config/applicationBatchContextPlan.xml crossRefAllPlansJob

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/batch/core/launch/support/CommandLineJobRunner
Jars in Classpath on linux :
springbatch/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar
springbatch/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
springbatch/lib/commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar
springbatch/lib/commons-lang3-3.3.2-javadoc.jar
springbatch/lib/commons-logging-1.2.jar
springbatch/lib/javax.batch-api-1.0.jar
springbatch/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar
springbatch/lib/ojdbc6.jar
springbatch/lib/spring-aop-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar
springbatch/lib/spring-aspects-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar
springbatch/lib/spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar
springbatch/lib/spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar
springbatch/lib/spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar
springbatch/lib/spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar
springbatch/lib/spring-core-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar
springbatch/lib/spring-expression-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar
springbatch/lib/spring-jdbc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar
springbatch/lib/spring-retry-1.1.2.RELEASE.jar
springbatch/lib/spring-tx-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar
```

Also, I want to know if there is any other way we can run spring batch jobs on linux without using the CommandLineJobRunner.

Answer (score 1):

Based looking at this [post](http://www.lucasward.net/2010/07/spring-batch-deployment-example.html) and this [post](http://rgordon.co.uk/blog/2012/01/20/getting-started-with-spring-batch/), you need to manually include all the jars on your classpath.

So basically:

```
java -cp ... org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner springbatch/config/applicationBatchContextPlan.xml crossRefAllPlansJob
```

The first post has a handy shell script to help with this.

In terms of other deployment options, you can deploy a spring batch application anywhere you can deploy spring (e.g. servlet container). Generally though, if it is the principal thing going on in the app, a plain old jar is probably the simplest option.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I already tried what was suggested in both the links.Please let me know if I am missing something else.

Comment: just realizing you didn't have any jars after the `-cp`. try removing the `-cp`

Comment: I have it in my actual command, I did not add it here, but put the jars in classpath

Answer (score 0):

The problem is resolved since a couple of days. The jars in the classpath were not getting picked up properly.After a couple of retries, it did and its working as expected now

Thanks to everyone for helping.

Thanks
Lakshmi